# MongoDB: Does findOne retrieve the whole collection from the database to the server

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, database-performance, query-performance

I am trying to make a website and I'm using mongoDB to store my database. I have a question about the performance about the query findOne which I've used widely. Does this query take the whole collection from the database to the server and then perform the iteration over it or does it perform the iteration on the database and just return the document to the server? Picking up the whole collection from the server will be an issue because transferring such a huge chunk of data will take time.

Comment: The server works it out of course. By background, databases are "BIG". So you would not pull 10 million rows in order to filter **one** out on the client would you now? [MongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/). People write documentation and tutorials in order to give basic background into things. Read the basics and then ask questions here.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how mongodb uses indexes would help you answer this question.  If you pass in parameters to the findOne query, and those parameters match an index on the collection then mongodb will use the index to find your results.  Without the index mongodb will need to scan the collection till it finds a match.

For example if you run a query like:

```
db.coll.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("5a0a0e6f29642fd7a970420c")})
```

then mongodb will know exactly which document you want since the _id field is unique and contains an index.  If you query on another field which isn't indexed then mongodb will need to do a COLLSCAN to find the document(s) to return.

Comment: Not quite correct. The collection will only be scanned until the first document matches. A complete collection scan will only be done when no document matches.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting official MongoDB documentation:

> findOne - Returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria on
>   the collection or view. If multiple documents satisfy the query, this
>   method returns the first document according to the natural order which
>   reflects the order of documents on the disk.

Obviously implied is that the database itself will only return one collection, and in addition, you could always use postman, or console.log to check what the server returns (if you're not sure).

Comment: One document is returned, not a collection. Terminology matters.